# How do I show time in ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net

I have a label in my asp.net web site that will shows the time. I want the output like here. in the morning like this: 08:26 and after 12 am,it shows 15:28

My code does not work. It only supports the first part.

```
DateTime tim = DateTime.Now;
int hh = p.GetHour(tim);
int mm = p.GetMinute(tim);
Label7.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("hh:mm");
```

Comment: I see the answer from marc_s, I think that it's important to point out that the format string "hh:mm" in your example do not represent variables, so you don't need to calculate a value for hh and mm, they actually present information from DateTime.Now that's why you can change from hh to HH

Comment: @MarkRabjohn : It does not work

Comment: It absolutely works as per the accepted answer, I was just trying supply some additional information. Only the 4th line of the example code is required, but you need to specify HH instead of hh.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [Custom date and time format strings docs page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings) - you can see:

> "hh"  The hour, using a 12-hour clock from 01 to 12.
> "HH"  The hour, using a 24-hour clock from 00 to 23.

So in your case - just use the capitalized `HH` for your formatting:

```
Label7.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm");
```

and you should get what you're looking for.